# Do exchange operators commute?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, identical-particles

I am new to quantum mechanics so please excuse the question if its answer is obvious.

Given an ensemble of $N$ identical particles and the exchange operators $U_{\alpha, \beta}$ and $U_{\alpha, \gamma}$, do these operators commute with each other?

I assume that they mathematically do commute, since you cannot tell the particles apart, but does this also make sense in a physical sense?

Answer (score 6):

If you have $N$ particles (or objects of any kind, really), you can permute them.  There are $N!$ different permutations, and they form a group of that size, the [*symmetric group* $S_{N}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group).  In general, this group is not commutative; in fact, $S_{3}$ is actually the smallest non-Abelian group.  You can observe the noncommutativity by looking at the action of two interchange permutations in $S_{3}$, $P_{12}$, which interchanges ${1,2,3}\rightarrow{2,1,3}$ and $P_{13}$, which interchanges ${1,2,3}\rightarrow{3,2,1}$.  If you act first with $P_{12}$, then $P_{13}$, you have ${1,2,3}\rightarrow{2,1,3}\rightarrow{3,1,2}$; however, if it is first $P_{13}$, then $P_{12}$, you instead get ${1,2,3}\rightarrow{3,2,1}\rightarrow{2,3,1}$.  Therefore, $P_{13}P_{12}\neq P_{12}P_{13}$; they are actually two different *cyclic* permutations.

In general, some of the interchange permutations do commute.  Specifically, $P_{ij}$ and $P_{kl}$ commute if they have an even number of indices in common.  For example, $P_{12}=P_{21}$ obviously commutes with itself, and it also commutes with $P_{34}$ (which exists whenever $N\geq 4$).  $P_{12}$ and $P_{34}$ swap entirely different sets of elements, so it is irrelevant in which order they are performed, $P_{12}P_{34}=P_{34}P_{12}$.

There is a lot of interesting group theory associated with the structure of the $S_{N}$ groups.  However, its applications in quantum mechanics tend to be fairly simple.  If the $N$ particles are identical, then no physical observable can depend on the ordering of the particles.  They only ways that this can happen is if the multiparticle wave functions $\Psi(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{N})$ are invariant under all permutations $P$, or they are invariant up to the sign of the permutation $\sigma(P)$.  (The sign of a permutation tells whether the number of two-particle swaps needed to produce that permutation is odd or even.)  These represent the two possibilities for particle statistics, $P|\Psi\rangle=|\Psi\rangle$ for bosons or $P|\Psi\rangle=(-1)^{\sigma(P)}|\Psi\rangle$ for fermions.

For example, in a system with just two bosons, one in the state $\phi_{1}$ and the other in an orthogonal state $\phi_{2}$, the full two-particle wave function is
$$\Psi(x_{1},x_{2})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\phi_{1}(x_{1})\phi_{2}(x_{2})+\phi_{1}(x_{2})\phi_{2}(x_{1})\right],$$
or, if they are the same state $\phi_{1}$,
$$\Psi(x_{1},x_{2})=\phi_{1}(x_{1})\phi_{1}(x_{2}).$$
Each of these wave functions is invariant under the exchange operator $P_{12}$, as $P_{12}\Psi(x_{1},x_{2})=\Psi(x_{2},x_{1})=\Psi(x_{1},x_{2})$. For fermions in the two different states, the two-particle wave function is
$$\Psi(x_{1},x_{2})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\phi_{1}(x_{1})\phi_{2}(x_{2})-\phi_{1}(x_{2})\phi_{2}(x_{1})\right],$$
and now $P_{12}\Psi(x_{1},x_{2})=\Psi(x_{2},x_{1})=-\Psi(x_{1},x_{2})$.  Moreover, with the fermions there is no way to place both particles in the same state, since a function like $\phi_{1}(x_{1})\phi_{1}(x_{2})$ is unavoidably symmetric under $x_{1}\leftrightarrow x_{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I am still somewhat struggling with the definition of indistinguishable/identical: Does this mean I have N ,say, electrons (without further specifying their quantum properties) or does this mean I am looking at N electrons which also have the same quantum properties (e.g. they're all in the spin up state and have the same energy (assuming considering N electron from N hydrogen atoms))?

Comment: The total state of the $N$-electron must be fully antisymmetric. This doesn’t mean they all occupy the same state: $\psi(x_1)\phi(x_2)-\psi(x_2)\phi(x_1)$ is antisymmetric although the single-electron states are different.